# C++ GUI QSpinBox's not showing up

Tags: c++, qt

My program compiles and displays my push buttons correctly but for some reason its not displaying the QSpinBox's. I'm pretty new at C++ qt GUI so any input would be greatly appreciated. I also checked if the spinners were being overlapped by the buttons but they were not.

```
//
// mainwindow.h

#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSpinBox>

namespace Ui {
  class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private slots:
    void clearx();
    void equalsx();
    void addx();
    void subtractx();
    void multiplyx();
    void dividex();
    void firstnumberx();
    void secondnumberx();
private:
    QLabel *label;
    QPushButton *equal;
    QPushButton *clear;
    QPushButton *equals;
    QPushButton *add;
    QPushButton *subtract;
    QPushButton *multiply;
    QPushButton *divide;
    QSpinBox *spinner;
    QSpinBox *spinner2;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

//
// mainwindow.cpp

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QTCore/QCoreApplication>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)

{
    label = new QLabel("0,this");
    label -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(75,75),QSize(50,200)));

    clear = new QPushButton("Clear", this);
    clear  -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(80,300),QSize(50,50)));
    connect(clear,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(clearx()));

    equal = new QPushButton("Equal", this);
    equal  -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(110,300),QSize(50,50)));
    connect(equal,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(equalx()));

    add = new QPushButton("Add", this);
    add -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(140,300),QSize(50,50)));
    connect(add,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(addx()));

    subtract = new QPushButton("Subtract", this);
    subtract -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(170,300),QSize(50,50)));
    connect(subtract,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(subtractx()));

    multiply = new QPushButton("Multiply", this);
    multiply -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(200,300),QSize(50,50)));
    connect(multiply,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(multiplyx()));

    divide = new QPushButton("Divide", this);
    divide -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(230,300),QSize(50,50)));
    connect(divide,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(dividex()));

    spinner = new QSpinBox;
    spinner -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(130,150),QSize(50,50)));
    connect(divide,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(firstnumberx()));
    spinner->setRange(1,10);

    spinner2 = new QSpinBox;
    spinner2 -> setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(190,150),QSize(50,50)));
    connect(divide,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(secondnumberx()));
    spinner2->setRange(1,10);
}


void MainWindow::clearx() {}
void MainWindow::equalsx() {}
void MainWindow::addx() {}
void MainWindow::subtractx() {}
void MainWindow::multiplyx() {}
void MainWindow::dividex() {}
void MainWindow::firstnumberx() {}
void MainWindow::secondnumberx() {}
MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `this` as parameter of `QSpinBox` constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a widget to display inside another widget, you need to set up a parent-child relationship. The simplest way to do this is to pass a pointer to the parent to the child's constructor as an argument.

For your `QSpinBox` objects, this is done like so:

```
spinner = new QSpinBox(this);
spinner2 = new QSpinBox(this);
```

The rest of your code is very laden with hard-coded geometries. For small GUIs, this might not be a problem but can become a bit of a nightmare to maintain for larger ones. Have you considered using [QtDesigner](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-manual.html) to design your GUI? You might also find the [layout management classes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/layout.html#id-f68c2fc4-a87f-4afb-aaac-e1528951a025) helpful in making your GUI designs better maintenance of positions and sizing of child widgets.